# When can a question end with 'then'?

Tags: grammar

- A: Chips are on sale, friend.
- B: I assume you're going to the store `then`?

Because chips are on sale, B would like to know if A is going to the store.

Is B's question proper English?

Is it only proper to use `then` at the end of a question when referring to an inferred period of time such as:

- A: I am going home this Summer.
- B: What will you be doing `then`?

Comment: _Then_ in this context means _in that case_; it does not refer to a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds okay.

> I assume you're going to the store then? [meaning *since chips are on sale*].

**Is it only proper to use then at the end of a question when referring
to an inferred period of time?**

I am trying to think of other questions ending with the word "then." A few come to mind.

1. What will we do between now and then? [meaning *in the interim* because a plan is being put in place to solve a problem but it cannot be implemented immediately.]
2. Are you okay with it, then?

"Then" refers to a condition the two discussed. They disagreed about a situation but finally they agreed to a condition. Just to be sure, one asks the other, "Are you okay with it, then?" [meaning *if I meet your condition*.]

**Answer**

I would argue that "then" in the proposed situation in the OP is not an "inferred period of time" at all, but a condition. A wants to go to the store because chips are on sale. That is a condition like in my Question #2. My Question #1 refers to a time period.

It appears, therefore, that "then" can be used in a variety of situations. The answer to your question is: No, "then" cannot be used only at the end of questions when inferring a period of time.

Comment: All the official examples I could find come with a preceding time statement like, "A: I'm going home this Summer.  B: What will you be doing then?" Very confusing.  I think we use it in a slang form when there is no inferred period of time.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'm thinking those were easy statements to come up with. My examples are definitely not slang. The sentence you started the OP with is rather unusual, perhaps slang. In my circles, it is more common for B to say, "I assume you are now going to the store?" meaning "now that the chips are on sale." I think "then" is one of those little "filler" words that can be used in many different ways.